# When to use asp:Button, etc instead of html?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have been wondering what the difference is with an asp:Button and a normal html button. Is it that the asp:Button when you click it can run C# code? I was wondering this because I am making a website and there is a button to hide/show a part of it (Using jquery). I don't think this is possible with the asp:Button though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in terms of the rendered HTML. The `asp:button` just allows for ASP.NET server-side postbacks via the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) using the [`OnClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick.aspx) event.

jQuery works with .NET controls because jQuery works with HTML, it's all the same. You just have to understand how to control the ASP.NET page and control events, when to use them and when to disable them.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure about them.

Comment: Votes are appreciated when the answer helps.